# Windows Updates take too much time to install on new virtual server instances

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2

The time it take for creating a new instance of Windows Server 2008 R2 and applying all the Windows updates (nearly 200 at the time of asking) takes way too long.  What other approaches can be used to stand up a new Windows Server 2008 R2 instance that includes all the updates?  Seems like simply checking for Windows Updates repeatedly until there are no more seems like not the best way.

Comment: Why don't you create a baseline virtual machine and just clone it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a fresh 2008 server with all the patches doesnt take long in my opinion.  2 hours maybe?  Perhaps you have a slow internet connection...

There are a couple of methods to speed up the process:  Imaging and [Slipstreaming](http://slipstream-win2k8.blogspot.com/).

For imaging, set up a Windows 2008 server and Sysprep it.  Then use an imaging program like Clonezilla or Ghost and take an image of it.  You can then deploy that image to 1 or 1000 (or more) machines at one time.

Slipstreaming allows you to create a new Windows install CD which has the patches integrated into it.

**Edit**:  I just reread the question.  I missed the virtual server part... Im tired.

You dont have to image the machine, since you have a virtual hard drive.  Sysprep the drive and copy/clone it, based on your virtual machines best practices.

Comment: Sysprep wouldn't be needed here, would it? Its the same hardware after all. Licensing would be the tricky bit

Comment: You would need sysprep in order to get a new SID.

Answer (score 0):

It really does depend on what your bottleneck is, but I've tended to use [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) to save time, and bandwidth to update systems. If you set it to automatic restart and recall, it'll apply sets of patches, reboot as needed and get your system to a fully patched up state, installing only the necessary patches. I've used it for years and its pretty reliable, and downloads the patches directly from microsoft.

You can either use this to prepare a base VM to clone, or to have it on a shared folder accessible to the VM and run it from there for each new VM.